# I can't install spring-security-core plugin in Grails

Tags: grails, spring-security

I have windows 7 and Grails-2.0.4. Trying to install plugin spring-security-core. I've tried from everywhere: `cmd`, Idea, SPS. Nothing works. Everywhere the same error:

```
!Error resolving  plugin [name: spring-security-core, group: org.grails.plugins, version: latest.integration(1.2.7.3 in SPS)]. Plugin not found.
!Error Plugin not found  for name [spring-security-core] and version[not specified(1.2.7.3 in SPS)]
```

I tried to put the zip-file of this plugin in different directories. Doesn't work. With connection everything is OK. Help me please.

Comment: Check to see if Grails Spring security integration requires another specific jar. this is a common confusion when working with Spring. Spring jars only include integration code that makes calls to other third party code. For example Spring-orm makes calls to Hibernate.jar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the `repositories` section of your BuildConfig dependencies, and add the following if it is not already there:

```
grailsRepo "http://grails.org/plugins"
```

The grails plugin repository moved earlier this year and the old repository does not contain any plugin versions released since April 2012. I don't remember exactly which versions of Grails will use the new repository by default, the change happened somewhere around 2.0.3/4.

Answer (score 1):

The preferred way to install it is to add a dependency in BuildConfig.groovy. The syntax for this is listed for each plugin, in this case from http://grails.org/plugin/spring-security-core: `compile`":spring-security-core:1.2.7.3"`(look for the 'Dependency' section at the top). So the`plugins` section of your BuildConfig.groovy should look like this:

```
plugins {
   runtime ":hibernate:$grailsVersion"
   build ":tomcat:$grailsVersion"
   ...
   compile ":spring-security-core:1.2.7.3"
}
```

Alternatively you can install it with the `install-plugin` script:

```
$ grails install-plugin spring-security-core
```

but the dependency approach is the better way.

Comment: Call me crazy, but I would set the log level to "warn" in BuildConfig.groovy for more information.

Comment: You are crazy Burt, why would you ever do that?